# JavaScript / jQuery multidimensional array (object) to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to send a array to php with this structure:

```
Array[0]['name'] = ...
Array[0]['def'] = ...
Array[1]['name'] = ...
Array[1]['def'] = ...
```

and so on....

To do this I have a multidimensional array object like this:

```
var allShapes = new Array();
$('.shape_name').each(function(index){
    allShapes[index] = new Array();
    allShapes[index]['name']=$(this).val();

    allShapes[index]['def']=$(this).closest("tr").find('*[id*=shape_def_]').val();
});
```

I send it through a post request to php:

```
$.post("../some.php", {
    'shape_defs' : allShapes
}, function() {

    console.log(allShapes);

}, "json").success(function() {
   console.log("success");
});
```

How do I have to iterate through thos array in php? Something goes wrong there......

The Array which comes as $_POST (after json_decode) has the following content:

```
[{"name":"Ta","def":"somestring"},{"name":"WSCall","def":"somestring"},{"name":"manual","def":"somestring"}]
```

How do I iterate to get the values of the keys?

Comment: you usually use for loops to loop over arrays, what goes wrong exactly?

Comment: The error message says: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Answer (score 3):

A common misunderstanding when people move from *PHP* to *JavaScript* seems to be that they don't realise non-integer *keys* are **not** a standard part of *Arrays* in *JavaScript*. The reason the interpreter doesn't complain is because *Array* inherits *Object* and *Object* can use any *String* as a *key*.

If you try to *Serialise* a *JavaScript Array* with non-standard *keys*, you'll lose them entirely as they can't be written in the form of an *Array literal*.

Therefore, you should be creating *Objects* as the items of `allShapes`, not *Arrays*.

```
var allShapes = []; // array literal
$('.shape_name').each(function (index) {
    allShapes[index] = { // object literal
        'name': $(this).val(),
        'def': $(this).closest("tr").find('*[id*=shape_def_]').val()
    };
});
```

Finally, convert the structure to *JSON* using `JSON.stringify`

```
var allShapesJSON = JSON.stringify(allShapes);
// send allShapesJSON..
```

Comment: Great catch, didn't even notice that inner array.

Comment: I added the data which comes as POST request to php above. How do I get the keys and values in php?

Answer (score 2):

Serializing your array using [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and then parsing it in PHP using [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) should fix your problem.  Complex data structures generally don't transfer well without encoding them.

Comment: As with virtually everything else in PHP, be sure to read the man page. `json_decode` can be a little quirky and has some restrictions on its use.

Comment: This won't fix the whole problem because `arr = []; arr['foo'] = 'bar'; JSON.stringify(arr); // "[]"`